# Does making variable volatile get rid of: Multithreaded correctness - Inconsistent synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, sonarqube

I'm getting Inconsistent synchronization error on sonar on following code.

```
public int getMessageCount()
{
return m_messageCount;
}

public void onMessage(XQMessage msg) throws XQServiceException
{
  synchronized(this)
  {
    m_messageCount--;
    // add the message to the result
    m_messages.add(msg);
    if (m_messageCount == 0)
    {
      // wake up client
      finished();
    }
  }
}
```

Error is on "return m_messageCount". If i make m_message volatile, will it solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @jameslarge Can you give this AtomicInteger suggestion in separate post

I was thinking, something like this:

```
static final int INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT = ...;

AtomicInteger messageCount = new AtomicInteger(INITIAL_MESSAGE_COUNT);

public int getMessageCount()
{
    return messageCount.get();
}

public void onMessage(XQMessage msg) throws XQServiceException
{
    int mc = messageCount.decrementAndGet();
    messages.add(msg);
    if (mc == 0) wake_up_client();
}
```

NOTE: the `messages.add()` call is inside a `synchronized` block in your implementation.  That is no longer the case in my version.  I don't know what `messages` is exactly, but if you were relying on the synchronized block to protect it, you will have to add synchronization back in.  At that point you might as well just go with your original version:  AtomicInteger is more complicated than just using a regular `int`.  I don't use it except when it allows me to implement some algorithm *without* using `synchronized` blocks.

---

P.S.;  What is supposed to happen if the message count is already zero when onMessage() is called?  Can that happen?  If it happens, you'll get a negative message count.  I don't have enough information to know whether that would be a good thing or a bad thing.

---

P.P.S.; What about that `XQServiceException`?  Both of our implementations will decrement the message count regardless of whether or not `messages.add()` throws an exception.  That might not be what you want.  I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `synchronized(this)` when you modify `m_messageCount` you can make the `getMessageCount()` method `synchronized` and that will solve your problem.

For example:

```
public synchronized int getMessageCount(){
    return m_messageCount;
}
```

Comment: If i make m_messageCount volatile will it also solve the issue ?

Comment: If you make it `volatile` you won't get the error anymore but the results will be inconsistent because the `m_messageCount` can be returned before it is modified in the `onMessage(....)` method.

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood I don't know what Sonar will say, but if I was your code reviewer, I would ask you to be consistent.  Either use `synchronized` everywhere your code accesses `m_messageCount`, or else make it an `AtomicInteger`, and use atomic methods (e.g., `.decrementAndGet()`) everywhere.

Comment: @Titus, even if it's `synchronized` everywhere, there's still a race condition.  If one thread calls `getMessage()` while another thread tries to call `onMessage()` at the same time, then one of them is going to win the race, and the value returned by getMessage() will depend on which thread won.  If that's a problem, then it can only be solved by synchronizing at a higher level in the program.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes you are right, that can happen. I suggested synchronization instead of a `volatile` variable because this way you are assured that those 2 methods won't execute at the same time.

Comment: @jameslarge Can you give this AtomicInteger suggestion in separate post so that I can verify it.

Comment: @Titus, declaring `m_messageCount` `volatile` would have the same net effect as declaring the getter `synchronized` because each read operation of a `volatile` is guaranteed to see the last write to the variable by any thread.

Comment: @MickMnemonic  not really, the `volatile` assures memory visibility while `synchronized` will control the execution order. In this case he `synchronizes` on `this` and a `synchronized` method will also synchronize on `this` which means that those 2 methods can't be executed at the same time, that isn't the case when it comes to a `volatile` object.

Comment: @Titus, yes, but the net effect will be the same, because as was pointed out by @jameslarge, the execution order between `getMessageCount()` and `onMessage()` is not synchronized. You can only guarantee that one thread executes either method at a time, but it does not really differ from not synchronizing the getter when the variable is `volatile`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I guess you are right, this things should be selected based on what you are trying to do and that isn't clear from the OP's question.